# Is it possible to catch a space in a variable?

Tags: shell

As the title states? Is it possible? I used the below codes but it cant determine if a variable has a space or not. Hope someone can help me

```
for file in `ls *.[Pp][Dd][Ff]`
do
  var1=`echo "$file" | sed -e "s/.*-\(.*\)-.*/\1/"`
  var2="document.num=.*$var1"
  var3=`grep -l ${var2} *xml`

case "$var3" in
*\ *)
    echo $var3 >> haha
    ;;
*)
    var4=`echo "$var3" | sed -e "s/-.*//"`
        varName="$var4.$file"
        echo ${var2}
        echo $var3
        mv $file $varName
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: [What are you trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) This is not a question you should have to answer about file names.

Comment: @l0b0 He's having problems because he's trying to [parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) rather than using file globs. But it's still an interesting question.

Comment: @CodeGnome Yeah, not parsing `ls` was going to be my answer, but then the question is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
var="ab"
#var="a b"

case "$var" in
*\ * ) echo "Has space" ;;
* ) echo "No space" ;;
esac
```

Depending on which variable is commented out, it prints `Has space` or `No space`

Answer (score 0):

### Use Bash Regular Expression Tests

If you want to be flexible about how you define whitespace, you can use Bash's built-in regular expression tests. For example:

```
# Variable has a space.
foo=' '
[[ $foo =~ [[:space:]] ]]; echo $?
0

# Variable has a tab.
foo=$'\t'
[[ $foo =~ [[:space:]] ]]; echo $?
0

# Variable has no whitespace because it's empty.
foo=''
[[ $foo =~ [[:space:]] ]]; echo $?
1
```